# Google Sheets ui.alert shows error on clicking elsewhere instead of OK button

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-sheets, google-apps-script, error-handling

I've created a Google Sheets script using Apps Script, and it includes a ui.alert that displays a dialogue box upon completing a function. Here's a snippet of the script:

```
function SuccessMessage() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('Congrats!', 'The task completed succesfully.', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that if I click on the OK button, the script runs fine and completes. But, if I click anywhere else on the sheet, an error pops up saying, **Script SuccessMessage experienced an error**, even though clicking OK or elsewhere essentially has the same result of closing the dialogue box.

Since there are no other functions to call upon clicking OK, I'm looking for a workaround or modification in the script that allows it to continue running and finish, even if I click elsewhere on the sheet instead of the OK button. Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you should report it as an is - [Issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566222)

Comment: Or you could try to use a toast or a custom dialog.

Comment: Look into Modal/Modeless dialog

Comment: LFRK. it is a known isuue

Comment: LFRK. it is a known issue Please check out on this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/317894979 
A +1 will be appreciated.